# Can't select vertices in mesh (.Blend File included)

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

I know it's part of the same mesh.  I highlighted it in orange before I press tab.

[image]

[image]

If you look closely, it's actually greyed out a little bit letting me know there is something odd.  They are unselectable.  It's almost like they are part of another object.  Please help.  Thanks.

Here is the file:

If you go into edit mode, you can't edit anything!

http://www.filedropper.com/exchange_1

Comment: Do you use a Mirror modifier ? Those faces could be on the left side of your mesh (and what you see is the mirrored faces)

Comment: No. only my armature.  I have preserve volume turned on though.  But that doesn't mean anything right?

Comment: I don't think Preserve Volume changes anything. Would you mind sharing the .blend file ?

Comment: Adding file to main post.

Comment: In this file those faces are hidden. Use Alt+H to unhide them. Did this solve the problem ?

Comment: Wait what?  How is it possible that you can see them in edit mode if the face are hidden?

Comment: OMG Thanks.  I must have some BS Blender mode open where if you hide vertices it still shows you the vertices.  Makes 0 sense.

Comment: To be fair I don't know WHY that solved the problem. If you hide other faces in your blend, they will be hidden (invisible) as intended.

Comment: Exactly, why am I STILL seeing them but are unable to edit them is beyond me.  There has to be some weird function I have turned on.

Comment: Yeah that's weird. It did some tests (especially Append the object in a clean blend file). I don't think the problem come from your Blender configuration, but rather from the mesh itself. Did you imported it from an other soft or something like that ?

Comment: I have not.  That mesh is native to the blend file.  This actually happened a few times, and I had to delete the entire mesh to start over.  Finally I can't take it anymore and ended up posting the question here.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the latest versions, you can't select some parts of the mesh that you can see, if you press Alt H you can select them again